# Making the header fixed only for cellular media with JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I've never really been good with front end designing here and I am stuck with something here. What I'm trying to achieve is make the header of website fixed only on mobile
Say

```
<div class='row' id='header' >&nbsp;</div>
```

I can use bootstrap and Foundation since I am familiar with the basics of it but I can't get my head around doing what I want. I want the header div to be fixed only for mobile devices so that when you're visiting from large screens/computer it's not fixed and goes with the flow with scrolling but only with mobile devices it remains fixed at top. Now I can simply change the css property with Jquery but I dont know how to find out and check for the device if it's big or small screen something like

```
if(deviceScreen==big){//keep it relative/absoolute} else //make it fixed
```

If it can be done with css only I would more than love to do it.

Another problem that I'm facing here is with the fixed elements(specifically a sidebar that only appears for small devices /main nav becomes sidebar) I want it to be fixed at the left but be scrollable in its own since some options are not visible because they dont fit in screen. I really need help here, the site wasn't developed by me. I am hired to make some backend changes and require to fix some front end bugs too that are mentioned here

Comment: you can use css media queries if you are happy to go down the route of using screen width to determine a mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Media Queries to determine the screen size.

If lets say the screen is no wider than 600 px:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
     #header {
           position:fixed;
           top:0;
     }
}
```

This css rule for header will only be applied when the screen is no wider than 600. And then set it fixed to top.

You can add multiple meda queries to a single dom element, adjusting it to your needs when the user changes browser width.

More about media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Thank you (Thanks to everybody else too for the answers)
But is there a way to apply javascript/jquery based on screensize? Because I have classes defined already in css and what I want to do is when the user is on a small screen classx is added to the element and when hes on a wide screen classy is added

Comment: Yes you can. Here's an example:

 `if ($(window).width() > 760) { $('#example-div').addClass('fixed'); }`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this by using css(Media Queries)

here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/3cndjsx1/

```
 @media (max-width: 600px) {
    header{
        position:fixed; 
        z-index:2;   
    }

    footer {   
        position:fixed; 
        z-index:2;
    }

 }
```

`Header` (you can change selectors according to your code) and `footer`(you can change selectors according to your code) will be fixed for screen size less the `600px`(you may also change the screen size in `css Media Queries`)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

You should also use 640px:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
     #header {
           position:fixed;
           top:0;
     }
}
```

Here a link where you can see the [media queries for standard devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Answer (score 0):

In case a media query will be good enough to approximate the target's device, I suggest you use orientation, like this...

```
@media (orientation:portrait) {
#header {
position:fixed; 
top:0;}
}
```

...as you probably don't want the fixed menu to show up on mobiles held horizontally either.